# Linq select from a list a property

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list `Vehicles` with some string properties.
I have another list `filterList` where the user select what properties he want.
In the `filterValues` should be the values of the properties that the user selected.
How should I do this?

So far I've thinking of something like this:

```
var filterValues = =new List<string>();
foreach(var filter in filterList)
{
    filterValues = vehicles.Select(x=>x. + filter).ToList();
}
```

But after this all the items from `filterValues` contains `x.filter`.
Thanks!

Comment: Is `FilterValues` supposed to be a list with properties to be selected? Please show the definition of the `vehicles` element type.

Comment: Use SelectMany() if you want to dive into nested list being properties of the class you are querying. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: FilterValues is suppose to have all the values of the property.

Answer (score 1):

I assume this would be your Vehicle class

```
public class Vehicle 
{
    public string Foo {set; get;}
    public string Bar {set; get;}
}


var filterValues = new List<string>();
vehicles.Select(x => filterValues.Any(f => f.Contains(x.Foo) || f.Contains(x.Bar))
                     .ToList();
```

Comment: The property that need to be in the filterValues is introduce by an user.

Comment: @RobertRPM that would be no problem and works with this solution, just add to filterValues after its declaration

Comment: `filterValues.Any(f => f.Contains(x.Foo) ||f.Contains(x.Bar) )`

Comment: @Desperado Thanks. This would have made more sence